# How to match regular expression with hex value?

Tags: c#, regex, hex

i have text file like this :

```
1:upx1:4D 00 68 6B 6A 68 6A:True
2:upx2:68 6B ?? 68 6A 00 02:False
3:upx3:FF 4D ?? 68 6B ?? 68:True
```

and i have string like this :

```
4D 5A 02 68 6B 6A
```

who match with line 3

i used this code to check regular expression path:

```
string readdb(string hash)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("db.txt"))
    {
        string re = string.Format(@"(?<row>\w*:)(?<title>\w*:)({0}:)(?<ep>\w*)", hash);

        String line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(re);
            Match match = regex.Match(line);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                return match.Groups[3].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        return "0";

    }

}
```

but my problem with ?? sign in file !
how can match any hex value instead of double question mark ?

Comment: How does `3:upx3:FF 4D ?? 68 6B ?? 68:True` match `4D 5A 02 68 6B 6A`?

Comment: only match "FF 4D ?? 68 6B ?? 68" with "4D 5A 02 68 6B 6A"

Comment: If `hash` is `4D 5A 02 68 6B 6A`, pass to `re` the `string.Join(" ", hash.Split().Select(x=>string.Format(@"(?:{0}|\?\?)", x)))`, see [what regex will look like](https://regex101.com/r/GCNG0g/1).

Comment: BTW, `Regex regex = new Regex(re);` must be declared before the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, move the `Regex regex = new Regex(re);` before the `while` loop, you will avoid regex object recreation related performance issue.

Next, you seem to need the exact sequence of 2 hex chars *OR* a double question mark. You may prepare your `hash` variable so that it could match in the way described above:

```
hash = string.Join(" ", hash.Split().Select(x=>string.Format(@"(?:{0}|\?\?)", x)).ToArray());
string re = string.Format(@"(?<row>\w*):(?<title>\w*):([^:]*{0}[^:]*):(?<ep>\w*)", hash);
```

The [regex will look like](https://regex101.com/r/GCNG0g/1):

```
(?:4D|\?\?) (?:5A|\?\?) (?:02|\?\?) (?:68|\?\?) (?:6B|\?\?) (?:6A|\?\?)
```

Each part matches either 2 hex chars or 2 `?`s.

Have a look at the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3Crow%3E%5Cw*%29%3A%28%3F%3Ctitle%3E%5Cw*%29%3A%28%5B%5E%3A%5D*%28%3F%3A4D%7C%5C%3F%5C%3F%29%20%28%3F%3A5A%7C%5C%3F%5C%3F%29%20%28%3F%3A02%7C%5C%3F%5C%3F%29%20%28%3F%3A68%7C%5C%3F%5C%3F%29%20%28%3F%3A6B%7C%5C%3F%5C%3F%29%20%28%3F%3A6A%7C%5C%3F%5C%3F%29%5B%5E%3A%5D*%29%3A%28%3F%3Cep%3E%5Cw*%29&i=1%3Aupx1%3A4D%2000%2068%2002%206B%206A%2068%3ATrue%0D%0A2%3Aupx2%3A68%206B%20%3F%3F%2002%2068%206A%2000%3AFalse%0D%0A3%3Aupx3%3AFF%204D%20%3F%3F%2002%2068%206B%20%3F%3F%3ATrue&o=m).

Comment: i received this error for first line :<br>The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments<br>Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'

Comment: Did you add `using System.Linq;`? Anyway, you may append `.ToArray()` at the end of the `Select` clause to convert the `IEnumerable<string>` to `string[]`.

Comment: i append .ToArray() and solve error but  the function is return 0 for all patern!

Comment: So, what is the string and what is the pattern? Are you sure your pattern matches the input string? Maybe it should not match.

Comment: when i have only hash in file this work good for example like this :
4D 00 68 02 6B 6A 68 6A
68 6B ?? 02 68 6A 00 02
FF 4D ?? 02 68 6B ?? 68
but i have other value delimited by ":" sign

Comment: You mean the spaces and `:` can delimit the hex values? Then replace all spaces with `[ :]` (add `.Replace(" ", "[ :]")`)

Comment: my database file have 4 column who delimited by ":" char.
my pattern is third column .
when string is match the function must return column 2 value for example "UPX3"

Comment: You should precise the requirements, because it is difficult to help further. Do you mean the `hash` is the *beginning* of the hex value column, or may appear anywhere inside that column? You may add `[^:]*` before/after `{0}` to allow the value to be anywhere inside that column. E,g, `@"(?<row>\w*:)(?<title>\w*:)([^:]*{0}[^:]*:)(?<ep>\w*)"`. Also, you may adjust the capturing group boundaries by moving the `)` before `:` (to exclude the colon from the capturing group value).

Comment: my problem exactly this : when hash is the beginning of hex column function work good but when not in beginning return 0

Comment: Please have a look at the updated regex in the answer. Try and let me know if that works as expected. I also added a regex demo. `${title}` group now contains `upx3` (click the *Table* tab link at the bottom to see the matches/captures).

Comment: how can solve my match problem with bigger length of hash than db.text value  ?

Comment: That does not sound related to the current question about matching `??`. No idea what you mean, you might need to log a new question.

Comment: i post new question in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045137/how-to-search-hex-pattern-with-wild-card-in-string