# How to search hex pattern with wild card in string?

Tags: c#, regex, hex

i have some hashes in this format :

```
row:title:hash:flag
1:upx1:4D 00 68 6B ?? 68 6A:True
2:upx2:68 6B ?? 68 6A 00 02:False
3:upx3:FF 4D ?? 68 6B ?? 68:True
```

and i have string like this:

```
02 4D 00 68 6B 6A 68 6A 00 02 00 00 00 FF 02 5A 68 6B 6A 68 6A 00 02 00
```

i need to match any hash with this string and match any hex value instead of double question mark 
for example hash in row 1 "4D 00 68 6B ?? 68 6A" match with my string

i used this code but always return "no"

```
    string str = "02 4D 00 68 6B 6A 68 6A 00 02 00 00 00 FF 02 5A 68 6B 6A 68 6A 00 02 00";
    string hash = "1:upx1:4D 00 68 6B ?? 68 6A:True";

    str = string.Join(" ", str.Split().Select(x => string.Format(@"(?:{0}|\?\?)", x)).ToArray());
    string sPattern = string.Format(@"(?<row>\w*:)(?<title>\w*:)([^:]*{0}[^:]*:)(?<ep>\w*)", hash);


    if (Regex.IsMatch(str, sPattern))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ok");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("no");
    }
```

Comment: It looks as if you want to  use the *hash* column value as a regex pattern to test the string against, right? Just extract it and replace the `?` with `.`.

Comment: yes but hash.Replace("?",".") not work !

Comment: Sure, *extract* the hash first. `var pattern = hash.Split(':')[2].Replace("?", ".")` and then `Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern)`.

Comment: it's work but i need to return title column as result of match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the whole row to be matching to string because string doesn't fit in the row. here is a working example of how to do it:

```
 public static void Test()
 {
       string str = "02 4D 00 68 6B 6A 68 6A 00 02 00 00 00 FF 02 5A 68 6B 6A 68 6A 00 02 00";
        string hash = "1:upx1:4D 00 68 6B ?? 68 6A:True";
        var parts = hash.Split(':');
        string title = parts[1];
        string hashhex = parts[2];
        string sPattern = hashhex.Replace("?", ".");
        Console.WriteLine($"Pattern={sPattern}");
        Console.WriteLine($"String={str}");

        if (Regex.IsMatch(str, sPattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ok");
            Console.WriteLine($"MatchedTitle={title}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Due to the big length of the string , what is your suggestion to improve performance?

Comment: @Tavakkoli, can you describe the relationship of strings to hashes? for example: matching 100 strings to 5 hashes, or 10 strings to 1000 hashes. Different ratios should have various best approaches to optimize this.

Comment: my string is a content a binary file and i search the hash in this content.

Comment: so only one binary file to search? how big is the file? also how many hashes are matched against this file?

Comment: yes every time is one binary file is searched , for example 500000 byte , my hash database about 3000 record

Comment: @Tavakkoli, to get that working faster I would suggest the following design: (1) the files is to be read into a byte[] array, (2) define a data structure for hash bytes - see below. (3) foreach hash run a matcher of the hash structure against the file byte[] array in memory. 

hash data structure: should be a list of continuous chunks, which are separated by the `??` wildcard, for example like this: 
`public class HashStruct { public string HashString; public HashStrip[] Strips; public string title; public int Row; public bool Flag; }`
see more below.

Comment: @Tavakkoli now definition of `HashStrip`: `public struct HashStrip { int offset; byte[] stripBytes; }`
So populate each `HashStruct` with original Hash data from your example above including the `HashString`, and then convert `HashString` into array of `HashStrips` like this:  this hash `4D 00 68 6B ?? 68 6A:` becomes 2 `HashStrips`: `{offset=0, stripBytes={x4d,0x00,x68,x6B}}, {offset=1,stripBytes={x68,x6A}}`, the `offset` is for skipping the `??` wildcard. The rest of the work is to write the matcher which will check that `HashStrips` are occurring in a file (with respecting the offsets)