# Regex matching for hexadecimals

Tags: regex, string

I'm working on a project (website) where I would like to validate various forms of Binary numbers. The first of which that I'd like to tackle is some Regex expression that handles the various 'valid' ways of representing hexadecimal digits. They are:

1. Leading '0x'
2. Leading'$'
3. Trailing 'h'

I'm just not sure how to handle this in Regex, as you can obviously only have ONE of the three options present at any one time:

This is the query that I've currently got:`(0x)?)[0-9A-Fa-f]`

- Works for the case of leading 0x
- (Obviously) doesn't detect leading $ or trailing h
- Not sure how to implement the 'only oone' functionality.

~~ Valid ~~

0xA, 0xa, 0x101, 0x747, 101h, $747

~~ Invalid ~~

A (just hexadecimal digit by itself), 0xa$ (Leading 0x and trailing h), $0xA (Leading $ and 0x)

Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps like this? `^(?:(?:0x|\$)[0-9A-Ha-h]+|[0-9A-Ha-h]+h)$` https://regex101.com/r/6obsVu/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird  since when are the letters `g` and `h` valid in a hexadecimal number?  Your regex accepts for instance `$ah3f`

Comment: @derpirscher Nice catch :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match regular expression with hex value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965313/how-to-match-regular-expression-with-hex-value)

Comment: No - Want to validate with `0x` and `$` leading chars as well as trailing `h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be defining all three forms as alternative

```
/^((0x[0-9a-f]+)|(\$[0-9a-f]+)|([0-9a-f]+h))$/i
```

You can also combine the first to forms with different prefixes into one

```
/^(((0x|\$)[a-f0-9]+)|([a-f0-9]+h))$/i
```

Since you didn't specify a particular language, I used javascript syntax, but in principle it's the same in other languages

- `/` denotes the beginning and the end of the regexp in JS, ie it does not belong to the regualar expression itself.
- `i` is an regex flag, to make the matching case insensitive, ie it matches `0xA`, `0Xa`, `aH` and `Ah`. If you don't want to match `0X` prefix or `H` suffix, you must remove the `i` flag and explicitely add `A-F` to the regex number portion
- `^` and `$` are the beginning and the end of the string. Thus it does only match a complete string and not when a regex is part of a bigger string. Ie it matches `"0xffff"` but not `"foo 0xffff bar"`
- `((0x|\$)[a-f0-9]+)` matches a valid hexadecimal number prefixed by either `0x` or `$`. As `$` is a special character in regular expressions, it must be escaped with `\` to be matched literally.
- `([a-f0-9]+h)` matches a valid hexadecimal number followed by exactly one `h`

Comment: Thanks! However, when I use this for typing validation, it doesn't allow the first character to be input, e.g. "0" or "$"

Comment: Well, if you do that validation on every keypress, no regex will. Because for the regex to match, you have to have a valid input ... Regexp processing can't guess what you will type next ...

Comment: So I tried adding an "OR" to your regex but that didn't work for some reason. Is there something I'm missing?
`/(?)|(0x)|^((0x[0-9a-f]+)|(\$[0-9a-f]+)|([0-9a-f]+h))$/i`

Comment: What do  you expect `(?)` to do? Furthermore, if you accept invalid input during typing and check this with the same regex that is used to validate the final result, it will accept that invalid input also in the end. So your validation won't work.

Comment: So if I want to allow "$", "0" and "0x" as valid regex strings, how would I add that? Sorry for being so irritating and changing the specification once you have already written a response.

Comment: You can have a regex like `/^((\$)|(0x?)|...(add original regex here))$/` But again, if you add that to the regex that is used to validate if the final input is indeed a valid hex number, your final validation will be wrong, because it will accept also `$` as a valid hex, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: OP, beautiful solution. Please edit with an extra escape character for the `\$` -> `\\$` in the original query to make this work in JS :)

Comment: @M.Choy If you use this in JS, like `var isvalid = /..../i.test(astring)` there is no need for an extra escape character. The extra escape character is only needed, if you construct your regexp from a string like `var regex = new RegExp("...")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternation with 2 alternatives, and if you don't need to refer to the capture groups afterwards you can use a non capture group `(?:`

```
^(?:(?:0x|\$)[0-9A-Fa-f]+|[0-9A-Fa-f]+h)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:0x|\$)[0-9A-Fa-f]+` Match eiter 0x or `$` and 1+ times any of the listed ranges
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9A-Fa-f]+h` Match 1+ times any of the listed ranges followed by `h`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lhu9pV/1)

---

You can not validate the whole pattern while typing, you have to validate the whole pattern while submitting / confirming.

What you might do is narrow down the possible options while typing like for example and at the end validate the whole pattern.

```
^(?:(?:0x?|\$)[a-f0-9]*|[a-f0-9]+h?)?
```

Regex demo